# New to python. Issues with Zeller's Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dayofweek

The only issue I am having is that the day of the week won't print after entering the year, month, and day when running the program. What am I missing or could I at least get a hint?

Here is my program (below) so far. Bear in mind, I am VERY new to python and coding in general, so please forgive the clunky code.

Thank you!

def main():

```
#Prompt User to enter year within range 1900 and 2100
year = eval(input("Enter year: "))

while(year < 1900 or year > 2100):
    year = eval(input("Enter year: "))
    print(year)

#Prompt User to enter month as a number
month = eval(input("Enter month: "))

while(month < 1 or month > 12):
    month = eval(input("Enter month: "))
    print(month)

#Prompt User to enter day as a number
day = eval(input("Enter day: "))

#Restrict the entry of numbered days based on the month and account for leap year in February
while((month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12) \
      and (day > 31 or day < 1)):
    day = eval(input("Enter day: "))

if(month == 2 and year % 4 == 0):
    while(day < 1 or day > 29):
      day = eval(input("Enter day: "))
    print(day)
elif(month == 2):
    while(day < 1 or day > 28):
        day = eval(input("Enter day: "))
        print(day)

if(month == 4,6,9,11):
    while(day < 1 or day > 30):
        day = eval(input("Enter day: "))
        print(day)

#Change in year if month is January or February
if((month == 1) or (month == 2)):
    year = year - 1

#Switch months so that March becomes the first month of the year and January/ February become the 11th and 12th months respectively
#Convert variables to algorithm variables (so a = month and b = day)
    if(month < 3):
     a = month + 10
    else:
     a = month - 2

     b = day

     c = year % 100

     d = year // 100

     #Compute r with algorithm
     w = (13 * a - 1) // 5

     x = c // 4

     y = d // 4

     z = w + x + y + b + c - 2 * d

     r = z % 7

     r = (r + 7) % 7

     #Set conditions so r[0,6] prints a day of the week [Sunday == 0 , Saturday == 6]
     if( r == 0):
         print("The day is Sunday")
     elif(r == 1):
         print("The day is Monday")
     elif(r == 2):
         print("The day is Tuesday")
     elif(r == 3):
         print("The day is Wednesday")
     elif(r == 4):
         print("The day is Thursday")
     elif(r == 5):
         print("The day is Friday")
     elif(r == 6):
         print("The day is Saturday")
```

main()

Comment: DON'T USE EVAL D: D: D: sorry for the yelling; use `int(input())` instead because `eval` is unsafe ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Indentation Levels

You didn't change your indentation level at line 47. If the month is less than 3, it will add 10 to it and then do nothing. Otherwise, it will proceed.

Actually, you didn't change your indentation level back at like 41. If the month is 1 or 2, it will subtract one from the year and then proceed; otherwise, it skips the whole thing. So you want this:

```
# etc

if 1 <= month <= 2:
    year -= 1

if month < 3:
    a = month + 10
else:
    a = month - 2

b = day

# etc
```